# how to copy a method insted of copy-paste code in C#?

Tags: c#

I got a method and I need to copy it and extend it with 1 parameter.. how to do it without copy-pasting the whole code ?

This is a Copy-paste version... how to short it ?

```
class HotelsClass {
    public Hotels getApartman(string Name, string Location, int minprice) {
        //some code here for fetching an apartman ...
    }

    public Hotels getHotel(string Name, string Location, int minprice, int beds) {
        //some code here for fetching a hotel ... has an extra "beds" parameter
    }
}
```

both functions do the same... just, the second function has an extra int beds parameter

Comment: Shorter than two keystrokes??

Comment: You're probably more interested in avoiding duplication in method bodies than avoiding duplication in method signatures, but you've left the method bodies out of your question.

Comment: If they both basically do the same thing, then they should be the same code.  why aren't you just having one call the other...or having both of them call some other function that does the grunt work?

Comment: @cHao, both functions do the same... just, the second function has an extra int beds parameter

Comment: @user3886199 If the second one actually does something with the value of `beds`, they don't do the same. And if the second one doesn't do anything with that value, why have that second method at all?

Comment: You need to make the code you copy/paste into a separate method, and use that method in these two methods.

Comment: Without seeing the body of the two methods it is not possible to say if you could refactor their code. (creating common methods called by both methods or calling getHotel from getApartment and passing a default beds value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have one as an optional parameter:

```
 public Hotels GetAccommodation(string name, string location, int minPrice, int? beds = null)
{
    if (beds.HasValue)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Although this is probably not the best design for your specific problem.